# .ajax async:true .click has different behavior than async:false in chrome

Tags: ajax, asynchronous

Let me start by saying that I know the difference between .ajax async:true an false, AND that I understand that it is GENERALLY not advisable to use synchronous calls.  With that said, I think I have a situation that calls for using async:false.

The basic problem is that I need to click a link (or button...or anything) and have the form data saved and when it is finished saving I need a new TAB opened in my browser (we use Chrome). This sounds simple, but the issue I have is that if I use a callback with .ajax and async:true I have to use location.open and that opens a new window (in chrome). This not acceptable to my end users. ALL other links open in new tab..

Here's where I am stuck...  If I call the async:true ajax onClick of a link, but don't use a callback, I just return true, It works and opens in a new tab. But I have no guarantee that the data was saved in time for the new window to render the report base on it. So I switch to async:false, and then I can make sure it works BUT it opens a new WINDOW not a TAB.  I certainly don't want to just loop and wait until the async:true returns...

What can I Do?

Here is the html Link:

```
<a id="btnSampleForm" href="/Report/Pdf?template=xyz....." target="_blank">Sample Form </a>
```

Here are my two codes functions.  Both save the data, but one opens in new tab, and one in new window.

This one Opens in new window...and I want it to open in new tab.

```
$('#btnSampleForm').click(function(e) {

    var retval = false;
    var request = $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: "/api/projects/@Model.ID",
        data: $('#project_form').serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true,
        async: false
    });
    request.success(function(x) {
        retval = true;
        dataChanged = false;
    });
    request.error(function (x) {
        alert('There was a problem saving the record. Please try to save the record manually before opening this report.');
        retval = false;
    });

    return retval;
    });
```

This one opens in new tab but I can't use it because I can't guarantee the save is done.

```
$('#btnSampleForm').click(function(e) {


    $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: "/api/projects/@Model.ID",
        data: $('#project_form').serialize(),
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true,
        async: true
    });

    return true;
});
```

Comment: I think that whether it opens in a new window vs. a tab depends largely on browser settings.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't explain why that behavior changes... If you look, I am not using code to open a new window. that is handled by the <a> tag itself. I just run some code before I let the link open. Its just that if I use asyn:false it changes the link to a new window not tab.